# How to show JSON data with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want show some data onClick from JSON. For now I am using different functions for each button but now are only 3. So this is what is working now

HTML

```
<div class="map">
        <div class="bullets">
            <div class="pin" id="pin3" name="ct3" type="" value="" onclick="ct3"></div>
            <div class="pin" id="pin2" name="ct2" type="" value="" onclick="ct2"></div>
            <div class="pin" id="pin1" name="ct1" type="" value="" onclick="ct1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img class="cover" src = "" id = "img" />
        <div class="title">
            <p id="header"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <p id="description"></p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

jQuery

```
function ct1(elem)
        {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "images/london.jpg";
            $('#header').text('London');
            $('#description').text('London is the capital and most populous city of England and the United Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.');
            $(".pin").removeClass('active');
            $('[name="ct1"]').addClass('active');
        }
```

So this way is working properly but instead to have multiple functions for each button I've created some arrays but I don't know how to call them onClick

jQuery

```
function refreshViewWithData(data)
        {
            var data = $.parseJSON(json_string);
            var img = '[{img: "images/london.jpg"},
                        {img: "images/manchester.jpg"},
                        {img: "images/newcastle.jpg"}]',
            var location = '[{"location":"London"},{"location":"Manchester"},{"location":"Newcastle upon Tynes"}]',
            var description = '[{"description":"London is the capital and most populous city of England and the United Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium."},
                {"description":"Manchester is a city in Greater Manchester, England, with a population of 514,417 in 2013. Located in the United Kingdoms second most populous urban area, which has a population of 2.55 million, ..."},
                {"description":"Newcastle upon Tyne, commonly known as Newcastle, is a city in the metropolitan county of Tyne and Wear in North East England. It is situated on the north western bank of the River Tynes estuary and centred 8.5 mi from the North Sea"}]'
            data = $.parseJSON(img);
            data = $.parseJSON(location);
            data = $.parseJSON(description);
            document.getElementById("img").src = "(data["img"])";
            $('#header').text(data["location"]);
            $('#description').text(data["description"]);
            $(".pin").removeClass('active');
            $('[name="ct1"]', '[name="ct2"]', '[name="ct3"]').addClass('active');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**DONE**

```
<div class="map">
        <div class="bullets">
            <div class="pin" id="pin3" name="ct3" type="" value="" onclick="ct(3)"></div>
            <div class="pin" id="pin2" name="ct2" type="" value="" onclick="ct(2)"></div>
            <div class="pin" id="pin1" name="ct1" type="" value="" onclick="ct(1)"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img class="cover" src = "" id = "img" />
        <div class="title">
            <p id="header"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <p id="description"></p>
        </div>

    </div>

     <script type = "text/javascript">
        var data = [
        {
          "image":"images/london.jpg",
          "title":"London",
          "desc":"London is the capital and most populous city of England and the United Kingdom. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium."
        },
        {
          "image":"images/manchester.jpg",
          "title":"Manchester",
          "desc":"Manchester is a city in Greater Manchester, England, with a population of 514,417 in 2013. Located in the United Kingdoms second most populous urban area, which has a population of 2.55 million, ..."
        },
        {
          "image":"images/newcastle.jpg",
          "title":"Newcastle upon Tyne",
          "desc":"Newcastle upon Tyne, commonly known as Newcastle, is a city in the metropolitan county of Tyne and Wear in North East England. It is situated on the north western bank of the River Tynes estuary and centred 8.5 mi from the North Sea"
        }
        ];        
        function ct(index){
            document.getElementById("img").src = data[index-1].image;
            $('#header').text(data[index].title);
            $('#description').text(data[index].desc);
            $( ".pin").removeClass('active');
            $('[name="ct"'+index+']').addClass('active');
        }
    </script>
```